# Ext JS - Focus on a textfield does not work with render listener in IE

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, extjs, extjs5

I currently have an issue with Internet Explorer where when rendering a textfield on a page, focusing on that element does not work as it should.

In Chrome, when I focus on that text field and enter a shortcut to search (F2) it searches the grid. However this functionality does not work in IE. Could anyone suggest a reason why or an alternative way that will work in all browsers? I cannot use the KeyMap component as it causes glitch issues with our screen.

The code I am using for the shortcut is below:

```
    xtype : textField,
    fieldLabel : 'Name',
    id : 'customerNameSearch',
    name : 'customerNameSearch',
    listeners : {
       render: function (field) {
          field.focus(); 
          field.el.dom.onkeydown = function (event) {
          if(event.code == "F2") {
             performGridSearch(name)
          }                         
       }
    }
```

The above code triggers searches in the grid in Chrome, but for some reason not IE.

Comment: Are you writting correctly the blocks open and closes keys  {     } ?

Comment: @levieraf Apologies, I was missing a curly bracket. I just copied and pasted from my code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ExtJS to listen for the `keydown` event and test for the F2 key in the event handler using `e.getKey()` or `e.getKeyName()`.  The listener would look like:

```
keydown: function (item, e) {
            if (e.getKey() === e.self.F2)
               alert(e.getKeyName());
         }
```

This should work in all browsers supported by ExtJS including IE.  Remember to set `enableKeyEvents: true` on the textfield.

Here is a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1om1) that works in Chrome and IE11.